# How to run lda using the jar files in mahout-distribution-0.7

Tags: mahout, lda

I have several jar files, namely, mahout-integration-0.7.jar, mahout-math-0.7.jar, mahout-core-0.7.jar, mahout-core-0.7-job.jar, mahout-examples-0.7.jar and mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar. How do i run LDA by calling a certain jar file, such as what should i declare first and its argument?

I have searched the examples on the internet but most of them

```
bin/mahout lda --paratemer1 --para2
```

but there is no such lda.class file in these jar files.
So what should i do to run LDA if i make use of those jar files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bin/mahout cvb for mahout 0.7. Check out this link for details:
https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/latent-dirichlet-allocation.html